# How to move a set of files named as numbers in ascending order to another directory?

Tags: command-line, bash

I have files inside a directory that are named as `00001.npy`, `00002.npy`, ..., `00150.npy`, etc. The file names are increasing in ascending order.

I want to move all files whose name is between `00008.npy` to `00180.npy` to another directory.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 7):

In bash you can use [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html):

```
mv {00008..180}.npy /destination/
```

Answer (score 7):

In zsh, you could use a shell glob of the form *<m-n>* to match a numeric range of filenames:

```
mv -nt path/to/destination/ -- <8-180>.npy
```

This has a couple of advantages over brace expansion, in particular it

1. works without error if not all files in the brace expansion `{00008..180}` are present
2. works even when the filenames are not zero-padded to the same length.

Comment: Wow! Awesome functionality! Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog see `man zshexpn` or (more easy to navigate) its HTML version [14.8.1 Glob Operators](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators)